# How do I get the Junit test results using Email-ext in Jenkins

Tags: junit, jenkins, email-ext

What do I need to add to the default html_gmail.jelly script to have it show the classes that were tested including how many tests were ran within each class?

When a Jenkins job is complete you can drill down to the Junit Test Results in an address that looks like:

http://somecompany.jenkins.com/view/App_Automation/job/Application_Under_Test/129/testReport/com.AUT.testing.mobile/

The test results are generated by the build.xml so is it just a matter of pointing to that xml file?

The email-ext page shows a clean example but not the tokens that are used to achieve that: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/download/attachments/3604514/html.jpg

Currently using the ${FAILED_TESTS} token generates a nice Tested; Failed; Skipped number, but nothing that points to which tests passed/failed/skipped. I would like to show the total number of tests including which tests were actually ran.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: What about adding the link to the tests results: http://my-host/jenkins/job/my-test-build/1/testReport ?

Answer (score 5):

OK I figured out how to display the pass and failed methods by adding var=pass or var=fail to the token of those assignments.

**First go to the Jelly script in the this path:**

~/.hudson/plugins/email-ext/WEB-INF/classes/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/automation.jelly

$DEFAULT_SUBJECT (${build.testResultAction?.failCount} ${build.testResultAction?.failureDiffString})

**SETTING UP THE CONFIG IN JENKINS**

```
DEFAULT SUBJECT:
$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS!

DEFAULT CONTENT:
$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:
```

Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.

```
Changes:
${CHANGES}

Changes Since Last Success
${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS}

Failed Tests:
${FAILED_TESTS}

Build Log:
${BUILD_LOG}

Total Amount of Tests:
${TEST_COUNTS, var}

Total = $TEST_COUNTS
Failed = ${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}

Total = $TEST_COUNTS
Passed = ${TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"}

Job Description:
${JOB_DESCRIPTION}
```

**Place this in the email job**
    ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html-with-health-and-console"}
Note the templates available are noted in the path `~/.hudson/plugins/email-ext/WEB-INF/classes/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/automation.jelly` or create your own.